# directory.getfile and windows phone 7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

In WP7 application, I am trying to get the name of all the images in the `Finiti` folder.

However the `string[] txtfiles` is always empty (null).

I think it is because I am writing a wrong link to the folder.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\Finiti");//, "*.jpg");
    MessageBox.Show(txtfiles[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string literal and an escape character, you only need one, not both.

Try using either

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Finiti");
```

or

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Finiti");
```

Otherwise the path will be interpretted as `C:\\Finiti` which isn't valid on Windows.

Comment: i try your method but it doesn't work, the string is always null. 2 weeks ago i found a post where were described the solution, but i don't remember where I read it. if I'm not mistaken the link for the folder is different between windows and windows phone.